# pip install: metadata-generation-failed in docker

Tags: docker, pip, alpine-linux

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.14

# Install python/pip
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1


RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN apk add python3-dev  # for python3.x installs
RUN apk add musl-dev


RUN apk add gcc

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/tap-stashstock
RUN mkdir -p /usr/singer
WORKDIR /usr/src/tap-stashstock

ADD . /usr/src/tap-stashstock
ADD singer /usr/singer

RUN pip3 install --upgrade .
```

This works and then I run `docker run -it stashstock-to-bigquery pip3 install target-bigquery` which results in this error

```
Collecting grpcio<2.0dev,>=1.38.1
  Downloading grpcio-1.44.0.tar.gz (21.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 21.4/21.4 MB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4wuwnk4b/grpcio_429c1ed72b4244a0a71ac7e9f1ec81c6/setup.py", line 256, in <module>
          if check_linker_need_libatomic():
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4wuwnk4b/grpcio_429c1ed72b4244a0a71ac7e9f1ec81c6/setup.py", line 203, in check_linker_need_libatomic
          cpp_test = subprocess.Popen([cxx, '-x', 'c++', '-std=c++11', '-'],
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
          raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c++'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

What am I missing from my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

This error may for not having a C/C++ compiler.
Try install `gcc` and `build-essensial` before pip installation.

Please follow the steps given in

[https://github.com/grpc/issues/24556](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24556)

Comment: I tried the advice there - installing g++, gcc. Specifically I added the line `RUN apk --update add gcc make cmake g++ zlib-dev`.  I keep getting the error now Failed Building Wheel for pyarrow

Comment: Yes, It does depends on the package your installing.